# Django Admin: Register extra staff Admin

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to register extra staff Admins such as a log in or sign up? or is the only way to add them in the Superuser Admin?

Comment: No, nothing stops you. But, the idea is not allowing anybody and everybody to register themselves as admin/superusers, so it is normally discouraged.

Comment: Well how exactly can I have them register themselves and make themselves a staff user? For this app I need them to use the Admin page but have restricted access so I make them a staff admin with certain restrictions to what they can do in the Admin page

Comment: Well, I told you the danger. But if you still want to do it, just set `is_admin=True` and `is_staff=True` on the `User` model

Answer (score 0):

You only have to set the `is_staff` flag on your user to `True`. Superusers bypass user perrmissions (all is permited).